# Visual Studio 2015 SDK CI server or force Rosyln

Tags: teamcity, roslyn, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to install the VS2015 SDK without installing Visual Studio? I would like to use the Rosyln compiler on our CI server (Team City), and need the SDK for the modelling sdk, T4 templates.

If not, is there an alternative - our project uses the Roslyn Style Cop implementation. Can i force Rosyln on a v12.0 toolset?

Comment: If you install the .NET SDK or latest Windows SDK,. you'll get the latest compiler, which is "Roslyn" based.

Comment: Team City does not execute code analysis extensions in this case.

Can the SDK be installed stand alone?

Comment: Installing and using Roslyn vs. installing and using the Visual Studio SDK are two separate things. Your question is confusing because you're somehow mixing the two.

Comment: Ok, so I need to use the Roslyn Compiler platform to access Code Analysis features - StyteCop Rosyln extensions. Ideally, this will be achieved using the latest compiler platform build tools (v14.0) however if I use that I need to install the latest modelling SDK - 14 toolset, for T4 tools as we use those in our code base.

However, I cannot install full visual studio on the CI server. Is it possible to install just the SDK?


The alternative is to use the nuget compiler platform packages, but that blows the packages size out.

Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: According to my findings you cannot install VS SDK 2015 without installing Visual Studio Itself. Therefore if you have t4 transformations in your code base, you require the modelling sdk, which requires vs sdk, which requires visual studio 2015 on the CI server. Not good :(